# How to align the color with React and tailwind.css

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, gradient

I'm using React with Tailwind CSS and I'm trying to do a skill progress bar with gradient color but the color don't match at all when it reaches a certain percentage.

For example 15% of the full width, it should be all blue and not different colors. How can I fix it?

Here's the code of it

[image]

Tailwind CSS

```
.progressbar {
    /* Size */
    height: 10px;

    /* Content alignment */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;

    /* Style */
    border-radius: 60px;
    background-color: #f0ecec;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
    /* Size */
    width: 0%;

    /* Style */
    background: rgb(255, 174, 105);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #12B0FF 0%, #4399E7 7%, #5282DF 15%, #6565D7 22%, #951CC1 30%, #A517B8 37%, #A717B3 45%, #AF18A8 52%, #C83E82 60%, #CF4978 67%, #DE5E62 75%, #E86E51 84%, #F27D42 93%, #FA8838 100%);
}



.progressbar-text-container {
    /* Size */
    width: 30px;

    /* Content alignment */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    /* Styling */
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

ProgressBar.js

```
import { motion, animate } from 'framer-motion';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Progressbar({ name, value })
{
    // Replaced useRef with useState
    const [progressText, setProgressText] = useState("0");

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        animate(parseInt(progressText), value, {
            duration: 1.5,
            onUpdate: (cv) =>
            {
                // Updating state instead of direct DOM manipulation
                setProgressText(cv.toFixed(0));
            }
        });
    }, [value]);

    return (
        <div className="progressbar-container py-2">
            <div className="flex py-1 justify-between">
                <p className="progress-bar-title">{name}</p>
                <div className="flex justify-end">
                    {/* Replaced ref with state variable */}
                    <p className="progress-bar-title">{progressText}</p>
                    <p className="progress-bar-title">%</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="progressbar">
                <motion.div
                    className="bar"
                    animate={{
                        width: `${value}%`,
                    }}
                    transition={{
                        duration: 1.5
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Progressbar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider having all the `.bar` elements the same `width` of `100%` so that their background gradients are the same size. Then, use [`clip-path:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)[`inset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/basic-shape/inset) to set their painted size:

```js
const { motion, animate } = Motion;
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Progressbar({ name, value })
{
    // Replaced useRef with useState
    const [progressText, setProgressText] = useState("0");

    useEffect(() =>
    {
        animate(parseInt(progressText), value, {
            duration: 1.5,
            onUpdate: (cv) =>
            {
                // Updating state instead of direct DOM manipulation
                setProgressText(cv.toFixed(0));
            }
        });
    }, [value]);

    return (
        <div className="progressbar-container py-2">
            <div className="flex py-1 justify-between">
                <p className="progress-bar-title">{name}</p>
                <div className="flex justify-end">
                    {/* Replaced ref with state variable */}
                    <p className="progress-bar-title">{progressText}</p>
                    <p className="progress-bar-title">%</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="progressbar">
                <motion.div
                    className="bar"
                    animate={{
                        clipPath: `inset(0 ${100 - value}% 0 0)`,
                    }}
                    transition={{
                        duration: 1.5
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Progressbar value={100} name="foo"/>
      <Progressbar value={50} name="bar"/>
      <Progressbar value={25} name="baz"/>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```css
.progressbar {
  /* Size */
  height: 10px;
  /* Content alignment */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  /* Style */
  border-radius: 60px;
  background-color: #f0ecec;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
  /* Size */
  width: 100%;
  /* Style */
  background: rgb(255, 174, 105);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #12B0FF 0%, #4399E7 7%, #5282DF 15%, #6565D7 22%, #951CC1 30%, #A517B8 37%, #A717B3 45%, #AF18A8 52%, #C83E82 60%, #CF4978 67%, #DE5E62 75%, #E86E51 84%, #F27D42 93%, #FA8838 100%);
  clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
}

.progressbar-text-container {
  /* Size */
  width: 30px;
  /* Content alignment */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* Styling */
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/framer-motion@10.16.1/dist/framer-motion.js" integrity="sha256-sS+KKDemoS6qg22Hi++wc5PAlgej08U6vDUKk/Y9K8Y=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```